# Ruby: Avoiding multiple "or" statements?

Tags: ruby, performance, optimization

I have several sections of code that have several grouped "or" conditionals, like this:

```
def some_method
 first_var || second_var || false
end
```

What's the best way to avoid this if there is one? I want it to remain compact and efficient though. My guess is that this is as good as it gets, but there's something in the back of mind that keeps saying that there must be some better way.

Comment: You goal is not clear.. sorry!

Comment: Those are not nested.

Comment: Actually it should be rather clear :)

Comment: I understand your objective, and don't see how you can improve on a series of `||`.  Since the variables (assuming they are not disguised methods :-) ) are local variables, they will always be `nil`.  It would be better if you made them instance variables or indicated they were preceded by other code in the method (e.g., `...` for the first line of the method).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to add `|| false`, but you don't want `nil` to be returned, you can do the following:

```
def some_method
  !!(first_var || second_var)
end
```

This way, if the return value of `(first_var || second_var)` is `nil` a `false` will be returned:

```
!!true
# => true
!!false
# => false
!!nil
# => false
```

Comment: @Arup I guess the OP wants this encapsulated within the method

Comment: I'm trying to think of a situation where one would want a method to return a truthy `true` or `false` (but not `nil`).  Ideas?

Comment: @Cary I agree it is not very ruby-ish, but I can think of some (remote) use cases, such as serialization `"do I have any var? - #{some_method}"`

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is remove the un-necessary `false` in the end as it will automatically evalute to false if `first_var` and `second_var` are false, rest looks like good to go:

```
def some_method
 first_var || second_var
end
```

If you are using `some_method` in a conditional statement than returning nil will also act as false, otherwise your original code is also clean and clear unless you want to so some fancy stuff, however I feel that will be overkill.

Comment: The reason that's there is because if one of those variables returns nil, then some_method will become nil.

Comment: `nil` is also false in conditional statement, in that case also it will return false only.

Comment: @TI45 Is that bad, though? Do you specifically need it to be `FalseClass` or `TrueClass`?

Comment: @saurabh No, try `false || nil`, it will result in `nil`.

Comment: yes, I meant to say, that it will work as `false` in any conritional statement.

Comment: It will *kind-of* work as `false`, unless nil is also a valid, significant, value. The method should return what the OP needs, which was true or false.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap it inside an array and use `any?`

```
  def some_method
    [first_var, second_var].any?
  end
```